# Setting OxyPlot PlotView max/min disabled after key/mouse events

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I have a Wpf application which shows a plotview and also has a button which calls a function for auto-scaling the plot based on its data.  The problem I am running into is that, if I interact with the plotview using the keyboard or mouse to pan/zoom, my button for auto-scaling, which simply sets the maximum and minimum values of the axes, doesn't cause the plotview to change visibly.  I have confirmed that the maximum/minimum values are modified in the object itself, but those changes do not show in the plotview.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public const int maxSamples = 45000;
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.PlotModel = new PlotModel();

        // the x-axis
        this.PlotModel.Axes.Add(new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis { 
                Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Bottom, 
                AbsoluteMinimum = 0, 
                AbsoluteMaximum = maxSamples,
                Minimum = 0,
                Maximum = maxSamples
            });

        // the y-axis
        this.PlotModel.Axes.Add(new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis { 
                Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Left, 
                Minimum = -100, 
                Maximum = 200 
            });
    }

    public PlotModel Ch1Model { get; private set; }

    public void AutoZoom()
    {
        double max;
        double min;

        // some code to determine the max/min values for the y-axis
        // ...

        ((LinearAxis)PlotModel.Axes[1]).Maximum = max;
        ((LinearAxis)PlotModel.Axes[1]).Minimum = min;

        PlotModel.InvalidatePlot(true);
    }
}
```

Again, calling AutoZoom() works until I interact with the plotview using the mouse/keyboard, and then AutoZoom sets the Max/Min values on the Axes, but the display doesn't update.  Any ideas of where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a question that's just been hanging out there for a while without an answer, but I found it still relevant when I was running into the same issue.

Internally to the `Axis` object, there is a `ViewMinimum` and `ViewMaximum` that are initialized to `double.NaN`.  Once you pan, zoom, etc with the mouse, these values get set to whatever the pan/zoom operation ended as.  The values are then given priority over `Minimum` and `Maximum` on any subsequent redraws of the `Axis` object.

In order to have the `PlotView` follow the specified `Minimum` and `Maximum`, you have to reset the axis by calling its `Reset()` method, then assign values to `Minimum` and `Maximum`.  Also note that once you set `Minimum` and `Maximum`, OxyPlot will use the same scaling in both the X and Y axes if the `PlotType` is set to `Cartesian`.  To not have this, set the `Model`'s `PlotType` to `PlotType.XY`.

For Instance:

```
public void AutoZoom()
{
    double max;
    double min;

    // some code to determine the max/min values for the y-axis
    // ...

    PlotModel.Axes[1].Reset(); //Reset the axis to clear ViewMinimum and ViewMaximum

    ((LinearAxis)PlotModel.Axes[1]).Maximum = max;
    ((LinearAxis)PlotModel.Axes[1]).Minimum = min;

    PlotModel.InvalidatePlot(true);
}
```